Swift package as a dependency of Framework project
I have a swift package that has a few classes marked with @objc. I have created a framework project and added Swift package as a dependency in Framework project. I want to import my swift package header file in my framework umbrella header file "iOSAuthFramework.h":
#import <iOSSDK/iOSAuthSDK-Swift.h>
I then created Xcframework out of framework project using:
xcodebuild archive \
      -workspace $WORKSPACE \
      -scheme $SCHEME \
      -configuration Release \
      -destination="generic/platform=${PLATFORM}" \
      -archivePath $ARCHIVE \
      -sdk $SDK \
      -derivedDataPath $BUILD_FOLDER \
      SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
      BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
      OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-no-verify-emitted-module-interface" \
      USE_HEADER_MAPS=YES \
      SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER=YES | tee xcodebuild.log | xcpretty

and
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
 -framework "${DEVICE_ARCHIVE}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" \
 -framework "${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" \
 -output "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcframework"

But it is not generating "iOSAuthSDK-Swift.h" in "headers" folder of Xcframework. It is only creating "iOSFramework.h" file. Although "iOSAuthSDK-Swift.h" file is generated in the build folder:
Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/iOSAuthFramework/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/iOSAuthSDK.build/Release-iphonesimulator/iOSAuthSDK.build/Objects-normal/arm64/iOSAuthSDK-Swift.h

